# Add/Delete Devices From SCCM Collection using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, wmi, sccm, configurationmanager

I am using .Net Core and **Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure** nuget package to query SCCM collections and successfully getting devices.

```
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
...
string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
string Query = "SELECT * FROM SCCM_collection where name ='$param'";
CimSession mySession = CimSession.Create("Computer_B");
IEnumerable<CimInstance> queryInstance = mySession.QueryInstances(Namespace, "WQL", Query);
```

However I need to programmatically Add/Delete membership rule to SCCM collection so I can manipulate devices inside SCCM collection as mentioned in this [blog](https://sylvester-lee.blogspot.com/2015/05/c-programmatically-adddelete-membership.html).

I am aware we can manipulate SCCM collections using .net framework package **microsoft.configurationmanagement.managementprovider** but since I am using .NET Core so this package can't be used.

Is there a way I can add/delete devices to/from SCCM collection using .Net Core ?

Comment: The managementprovider package is just a wrapper so that you can use your old vbscript wmi code in .net easily but afaik the commands are all just pure wmi. So you should be able to do it with standard wmi code. I have never done anything sccm related in .net core, but if I understood correctly all the basic stuff is the same, so if I show you an example of .net 4.7 code that does not use the managementprovider it should work in core as well right?

Answer (score 0):

I never found any official word on this but as far as I understand it the microsoft.configurationmanagement.managementprovider is just some sort of wrapper that allows you to easily port your old vbscript examples that follow MS guidelines to sccm. All those examples just invoke WMI Methods, there is nothing SCCM specific about them so you can always use basic WMI to write this without additional stuff.

So you can just use System.Management and then write it like this:

```
ManagementClass collQuery = new ManagementClass(@"\\<siteserver>\root\sms\site_<sitecode>", "SMS_CollectionRuleQuery", null);
ManagementObject collQueryInstance = collQuery.CreateInstance();

collQueryInstance["QueryExpression"] = "Select * from SMS_R_System";
collQueryInstance["RuleName"] = "Members of collection";

ManagementObject collInstance = new ManagementObject(@"\\<siteserver>\root\SMS\site_<sitecode>:SMS_Collection.CollectionID='<CollID>'");
ManagementBaseObject inParams = collInstance.GetMethodParameters("AddMembershipRule");

inParams.SetPropertyValue("collectionRule", collQueryInstance);

ManagementBaseObject outParams = collInstance.InvokeMethod("AddMembershipRule", inParams, null);
```

and it should work. Of course you have to translate all the calls into the "normal" WMI Syntax but I think this example should provide you with the basics